# How to print several lines to stdout while overwriting what was printed before?

Tags: c, printf, carriage-return

I'm a student currently developing a version of Othello for a university project.

It is mostly finalized so I'm looking for things I can improve on. One of these is making the board (which is printed to stdout) just replace the previous one with each play, ensuring the terminal doesn't move.

Below is the most recent attempt at doing so:

```
char c = ' ';
fflush(stdout);
contaPecas(e, pecas);
printf("\n\r* X-%d |SCORE| O-%d *   \n\r\n\r  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  "" | N <peça>para novo jogo "
       "em que o primeiro a jogar é o jogador com peça.\n\r", pecas->x, pecas->y);

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if (j == 0)
            printf("%d ", i+1);

        if (opcao == 1 && verificaValida(i,j,turno) == 1)
            c = '.';
        else if (opcao == 2 && (*turno)->N != 0 && i == sugestao->y && j == sugestao->x)
            c = '?';
        else
            switch (e.grelha[i][j]) {
                case VALOR_O:
                    c = 'O';
                    break;
                case VALOR_X:
                    c = 'X';
                    break;
                case VAZIA:
                    c = '-';
                    break;
            }
        printf("%c ", c);
    }

    switch (i) {
            case 0:
                printf("  | A para novo jogo contra bot. O jogador comeca com peça X.\n\r");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("  | L<ficheiro>para ler um jogo de ficheiro.\n\r");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("  | E <ficheiro> escrever em ficheiro estado do jogo.\n\r");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("  | J<L,C>jogar peça atual na posição (l,c).\n\r");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("  | S para imprimir um ponto ‘.’nas posições com jogada válida.\n\r");
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("  | H para sugestão de jogada. Deve ser colocado um ‘?’no sitio sugerido.\n\r");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("  | U para desfazer a última jogada(Undo).\n\r");
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("  | Q para sair do jogo.\n\r");
                break;
        }
    }
if (e.peca == 0) printf("\n\r");
else if (e.peca == VALOR_X) printf("Turn: X\n\r\n\r");
else printf("Turn: O\n\r\n\r");

if (opcao == 2 && (*turno)->N != 0)
    printf("A melhor jogada é %d %d.\n\r", sugestao->y+1, sugestao->x+1);
```

}

I expected with fflush(stdout) it would erase the previous prints, and with '\r' that it would just write in the same place as it had previously, but it keeps writing under what was already written and making the terminal move. Any ideas on what I could do to fix this?

Comment: One major improvement you can do is to always code in English, with English variable and function names.

Comment: You might also be interested in calling `system("clear");` to clear the current terminal

Comment: @Lundin I normally would, but it was specifically asked that we work from a template that is in Portuguese, so I figured I'd keep the rest in Portuguese. It looks very wrong to me as well!

Answer (score 2):

Even using `\r`, the standard functions (`scanf`, `fgets` ...) reads from `stdin` until a <kbd>Return</kbd> is pressed, in these cases the cursor always goes down (consumes `\n`) to the next line of the console.

You need to use some specialized library, you can check `ncurses` on unixes or the console API in windows.

Another option (if you are under a vt100 compatible terminal) is using console codes:

```
#define gotoxy(x,y) printf("\033[%d;%dH", (x), (y))
```

(`man console_codes` to get more info)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use conio, that's obsolete DOS crap. In Windows, use the console API directly.

Comment: @Lundin, you mean Turbo C  is obsolete? you are right, edited ;)

Comment: Don't knock my Borland Turbo C/C++ for DOS. I got it in 89 and it was good then. Even came with tasm... That was only a couple of years ago. Must still be good, right? It even used the 8087 Math Co-processor on my 386 board!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yeah! Turbo C rules  https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/Jx8AAOSwgzBcM1cO/s-l500.jpg

Comment: Yep, still have my drawer full of 360k and 1.2m 5.25 floppies (and I still have a couple of drives that read them....`:)`

Comment: I keep them too! QuattroPro, WordPerfect, Lotus 123 .... they always got stuck on the last dkt!

Comment: ...and coding in Turbo C in today is pretty much equivalent to writing your business letters in WordPerfect, then sending them on a floppy over regular mail.

Comment: @Lundin, yes, but I see a lot of posts asking how to configure conio in code::blocks, is it still really used in production or only for academic things?

Comment: Apparently the school system in India loves Turbo C because they've been using it for 30 years, so it must be real good still. Educating future MS DOS programmers.